# Асинхронный запуск одного GIF для десяти картинок

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть один файл gif с вращением монтеки.Этот файл я использую для десяти картинок.Но они вращаються синхронно. А мне надо чтоб они вращались не синхронно.

Comment: второй Gif файл не пробовали?

Comment: нет потому что это увеличит вес html

Comment: Покажите, как у вас сделано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать что-то такое на css js..

```js
let coin = document.querySelectorAll('.coin');
let rnd = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) * 10
}

coin.forEach(e => {
  //с разной задержкой
  setTimeout(() => {
    e.classList.toggle('anim')
  }, rnd(), e);

  //по клику
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    event.target.classList.toggle('anim')
  })
})
```

```css
#cont {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black inset;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.coin {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: no-repeat center/cover url("https://www.cbr.ru/StaticHtml/File/98254/97(09)_5R_A.gif");
  clip-path: circle(49px at 50% 50%);
  /*обрезает белый фон картинки gif здесь не проигрывается это картинка*/
}

.anim {
  animation: rt infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes rt {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0) scaleX(1);
    background: no-repeat center/cover url("https://www.cbr.ru/StaticHtml/File/98254/97(09)_5R_A.gif");
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(0.5turn) scaleX(-1);
    background: no-repeat center/cover url("https://www.cbr.ru/StaticHtml/File/98254/97(09)_5R_R.gif");
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(1turn) scaleX(1);
    background: no-repeat center/cover url("https://www.cbr.ru/StaticHtml/File/98254/97(09)_5R_A.gif");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='cont'>
  <div class='coin anim'></div>
  <div class='coin'></div>
  <div class='coin'></div>
  <div class='coin'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает идеально.

Comment: На здоровье! :)

Comment: А gif можно используя гиф а не jpg. У меня сложное вращение gif на 20 кадров. И проблема втом что не в зависимости когда появилось gif крутиться они так будто родились одновременно

Comment: @ЭвгенЭвгенов при анимации гиф, в не зависимости от того, в скольких "блоках" отображается, очередь перерисовки не смещается, это один и тот же файл. При частоте 60 кадров в секунду, браузер имеет 16.7 миллисекунд, чтобы выполнить все скрипты, пересчитать стили, скомпоновать слои и отрисовать новый кадр. Новый кадр гиф будет отображаться раз в ~16.7мс не зависимо от времени "загрузки". Т.к. файл один и тот же, просто отображается в разных "блоках" и управляет отрисовкой браузер, перерисовываться будет синхронно. Коммент в css  "gif здесь не проигрывается это картинка" имеется ввиду статичная.